# How can I shorten the calculation time effectively?

Tags: performance-tuning, random

I try to do a big simulation like below.

(However, I do not change the sizes I want to 10 ^ 5, 10 ^ 7, 10 ^ 9.)

```
n = RandomSample[all = Range[10^7], 2*10^5]; 
r = RandomChoice[all, 10^9];
Total@Table[Count[n, r[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[r]}]
```

However, the calculation takes too long.

How can I shorten the calculation time effectively?

Comment: `RandomInteger` seems to cut more than 50% of the time off of `Range` and `RandomSample`.  It can also be used in place of `RandomChoice` if combined with `Table`.

Comment: @kickert `RandomInteger` does not produce the same results as `RandomSample`.

Comment: Got ahead of myself, I should have suggested it as a replacement for the `RandomChoice` on the full range.  Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of building the long list `r` of random numbers, you could sample directly from the distribution of results: replace the third line of your code with

```
RandomVariate[BinomialDistribution[Length[r], Length[n]/Length[all]]]
```

to get a result instantaneously. Or is this cheating?

Answer (score 11):

This should have the same effect and runs in about 7.6 seconds.

```
AbsoluteTiming[

 m = 10^7;
 l = 4;
 n = RandomSample[1 ;; m, 2 10^5];
 u = Normal[SparseArray[Partition[n, 1] -> 1, {m}]];
 sum = Total@ParallelTable[
    Total[u[[RandomChoice[1 ;; m, 10^l]]]],
    {10^(9 - l)},
    Method -> "CoarsestGrained"
    ]

 ]
```

The important points are:

- Using `RandomSample[1 ;; m, ...]` and `RandomChoice[1 ;; m, ...]`. This allows us to handle also rather large `m`.
- Conversion of the very expensive `Count` operation (which goes through the whole list `n` $10^9$ times!) into a simple read operation from the (packed!) array `u`.
- Chopping the vector `r` into small pieces so that it never has to be stored in RAM; if I computed correctly, `r` would need more than 7 GB of RAM. Since the pseudorandom numbers in the array returned from `RandomChoice` are pairwise independent, we may just call `RandomChoice[1 ;; m, 10^l]` multiple times, do the counts and sum then up in the end with `Total`.

Comment: Interesting. The `Span`form has been available since 10.3, and I've never noticed it.

Comment: Thank you very much. Became very helpful !!

Comment: @user21427 You're welcome!